# how to get multiple strings of same matches in lastindexof?

Tags: java

### how to get multiple strings of same matches in lastindexof?

In this i want to get two strings in lastindexof which is from 08:24:49 to 08:24:52, but it will print only one 08:24:52 but i want two 08:24:52 to get.

2017-05-05 08:24:49,408 WARN

2017-05-05 08:24:49,408 WARN

2017-05-05 08:24:52,408 WARN

2017-05-05 08:24:52,408 WARN

```
public class MeteringlogBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Date date10;
private Date date11;
private String d;
private String d1;
private String s;
private String text;
private FileWriter fw;
private BufferedWriter bw;
private String Fn = "C:/Users/swetha.papireddy/Documents/new/filename.txt";

public Date getDate11() {
    return date11;
}

public void setDate11(Date date11) {
    this.date11 = date11;

}

private String environment;

public String getEnvironment() {

    return environment;
}

public void setEnvironment(String environment) {

    this.environment = environment;
}

public Date getDate10() {
    return date10;
}

public void setDate10(Date date10) {
    this.date10 = date10;
}

public void save() throws IOException, NullPointerException {

    try {
        File file = new File(getEnvironment() + "/ischange.log");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            stringBuilder.append("\n");
        }
        fileReader.close();

        System.out.println("Contents of file:");
        s = stringBuilder.toString();
        System.out.println(s);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // System.out.println(date10);
    d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date10);
    System.out.println("date:-" + d);
    d1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date11);
    System.out.println("date:-" + d1);
    fw = new FileWriter(Fn);
    bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write(s);
    bw.close();

    File file = new File(Fn);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    fis.read(bytes);
    fis.close();
    String text = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
    String str1 = new String(d);
    String str2 = new String(d1);
    System.out.println(text.substring(text.indexOf(str1),
            text.lastIndexOf(str2)));
}
```

output:
2017-05-05 08:24:49,408 WARN

2017-05-05 08:24:49,408 WARN

2017-05-05 08:24:52,408 WARN

Comment: How you fill date10 and date11

Comment: [`String#indexOf(String, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-int-)?

Comment: Hint: you never ever put down "throws Nullpointerexception" in the signature of a method. Makes no sense and indicates that you don't understand what that exception means.

Comment: *Unrelated:* Don't use `StringBuffer`, Instead, use `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Why are you writing the file in the default character set, then reading it back in UTF-8? Any reason for trying to corrupt the text that way? Why even do that? You have the text in memory so used it. --- Also, what is the point of `new String(d)`, given that `d` is already a `String`?

Comment: Why with `lastIndexOf()`? Very tricky that way, but very easy with `indexOf()`.

Comment: The values of d and d1 contains the option selected through dropdown by the user  And next from there it fetches the textfile but i need to display only the contents between d and d1 that is to and from date.  The point over here is the last index is stopping as soon as it finds d1 without checking further. Any help is accepted, Thanks in prior.

Comment: You haven't answered my question in any way.

Comment: indexOf() returns the first position which is my from date and lastIndexOf is for last position which is to date in my case.

Comment: i have uploaded my whole code, look into it.

Answer (score 0):

```
String text ="2017-05-05 08:24:49,408 WARN 2017-05-05 08:24:49,408 WARN 2017-05-05 08:24:52,408 WARN 2017-05-05 08:24:52,408 WARN";
        String searchStr = "08:24:52";
        while(text.length()>= searchStr.length() && text.contains(searchStr)){
            text = text.substring(text.indexOf(searchStr)+searchStr.length());
            System.out.println(searchStr);
        }
```

Hope this answers your question..

Answer (score 0):

I really don't get what you want to do, but I think you can not have the general string class.
Why don't you use Pattern and Match class to find your string out of this situation?

The code you gave is not completed for me so, I've modified it appending a small chunk of code.

Then, if i have a log file format like this below.

> > ischange.log file

```
2017-05-05 08:24:49,408 WARN

2017-05-05 08:24:49,408 WARN

2017-05-05 08:24:52,408 WARN

2017-05-05 08:24:52,408 WARN
```

I make the final out file without empty string, named ischange.log.out, like

```
2017-05-05 08:24:49,408 WARN
2017-05-05 08:24:49,408 WARN
2017-05-05 08:24:52,408 WARN
2017-05-05 08:24:52,408 WARN
```

The Full source code is here

```
    private String getEnvironment() {
    return ".";
}

public void save() throws IOException, NullPointerException {
    String s = null;
    String d = null, d1 = null;
    Date date10 = new Date();
    Date date11 = new Date();

    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    String Fn = getEnvironment() + "/ischange.log.out";
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    TreeMap<String, String> hashStore = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    FileInputStream fis = null;

    try {
        File file = new File(getEnvironment() + "/ischange.log");

        if (!file.exists())
            return;

        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.equals(""))
                continue;

            stringBuffer.append(line);
            stringBuffer.append("\n");

            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");

            if (st.countTokens() != 2)
                continue;

            hashStore.put(st.nextToken(), st.nextToken());
        }

        System.out.println("Contents of file:");
        s = stringBuffer.toString();
        System.out.println(s);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        bufferedReader.close();
    }

    Set<String> eSet = hashStore.keySet();
    String[] outDate = new String[2];
    outDate = eSet.toArray(outDate);
    try {
        date10 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(outDate[0]);
        date11 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(outDate[1]);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String formatStr = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    formatStr = "HH:mm:ss";

    d = new SimpleDateFormat(formatStr).format(date10);
    System.out.println("date:- " + d);
    d1 = new SimpleDateFormat(formatStr).format(date11);
    System.out.println("date:- " + d1);

    try
    {
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(Fn));
        bw.write(s);
    }
    finally
    {
        bw.close();
    }

    byte[] contents = null;

    try
    {
        int len = s.getBytes().length;
        fis = new FileInputStream(new File(Fn));
        contents = new byte[len];
        fis.read(contents, 0, len);
    }
    finally
    {
        fis.close();
    }

    String text = new String(contents, "UTF-8");

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(d);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(" match : " + matcher.group());
    } 

    pattern = Pattern.compile(d1);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(" match : " + matcher.group());
    } 

    // String text = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
    //String str1 = new String(d);
    //String str2 = new String(d1);

    //int index = text.indexOf(str1);
    //int indexlast = text.lastIndexOf(str2);
    //System.out.println("index:- " + index + " indexlast: " + indexlast);

    // System.out.println(text.substring(index,indexlast));

    //System.out.println(text.substring(text.indexOf(str1), text.lastIndexOf(str2)));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        new StringTest().save();
    } catch (NullPointerException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The output of the code must be as you are expecting.

```
Contents of file:
2017-05-05 08:24:49,408 WARN
2017-05-05 08:24:49,408 WARN
2017-05-05 08:24:52,408 WARN
2017-05-05 08:24:52,408 WARN

date:- 08:24:49
date:- 08:24:52
 match : 08:24:49
 match : 08:24:49
 match : 08:24:52
 match : 08:24:52
```

Using TreeMap for read a string line by line and sorting it at the same time.

```
TreeMap<String, String> hashStore = new TreeMap<String, String>();
...
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.equals(""))
                    continue;

                stringBuffer.append(line);
                stringBuffer.append("\n");

                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");

                if (st.countTokens() != 2)
                    continue;

                hashStore.put(st.nextToken(), st.nextToken());
            }
```

Then just finding it with unique date strings stored by the hashStore processed above .

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(d);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(" match : " + matcher.group());
        } 

        pattern = Pattern.compile(d1);
        matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(" match : " + matcher.group());
        }
```

If you have a file as following..

```
2017-05-05 08:24:46,397 WARN [pool-80-thread.PhaseInterceptorChain... 
2017-05-05 08:24:49,444 ERROR [pool-80-thread-1] icationExceptionOutInterceptor... 
2017-05-05 08:24:49,408 WARN [pool-78-thread-1.. 
2017-05-05 08:24:52,408 ERROR [pool-78-thread-1... 
2017-05-05 08:24:52,408 ERROR [pool-78-thread-1... {... = contents inside}
```

My implementation would be two conditions.
1. Length of date string is fixed, this is 19 bytes length
2. Log level strings are also fixed, which are one of warn,debug or error.

This is my idea.

```
public void save2() throws IOException, NullPointerException {
        final String LOG_LVL[] = {"WARN", "DEBUG", "ERROR"};


        final class LogData
        {
            private final String dateString;
            private final String contents;
            private final int logtypelen;

            LogData(final String dateString, final String contents, final int logtypelen)
            {
                this.dateString = dateString;
                this.contents = contents;
                this.logtypelen = logtypelen;
            }

            String getDateString()
            {
                return dateString.substring(0,19);
            }

            String getContents()
            {
                return contents.substring(logtypelen,contents.length());
            }   
        }

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        List<LogData> strList = new ArrayList<LogData>();

        try {
            File file = new File(getEnvironment() + "/ischange2.log");

            if (!file.exists())
                return;

            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.equals(""))
                    continue;
                int i = 0;
                int idx = -1;
                for(i = 0; i < LOG_LVL.length; i++)
                    if((idx = line.indexOf(LOG_LVL[i])) != -1) break;


                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");

                if (st.countTokens() != 2)
                    continue;

                strList.add(new LogData(st.nextToken(), line, idx+LOG_LVL[i].length()));
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            bufferedReader.close();
        }


        for(LogData data : strList)
        {
            System.out.println("date is [" + data.getDateString() + "]===== contents is [" + data.getContents() + "]");
        }
    }
```

The out put is

```
date is [2017-05-05 08:24:46]===== contents is [ [pool-80-thread.PhaseInterceptorChain... ]
date is [2017-05-05 08:24:49]===== contents is [ [pool-80-thread-1] icationExceptionOutInterceptor... ]
date is [2017-05-05 08:24:49]===== contents is [ [pool-78-thread-1.. ]
date is [2017-05-05 08:24:52]===== contents is [ [pool-78-thread-1... ]
date is [2017-05-05 08:24:52]===== contents is [ [pool-78-thread-1... {... = contents inside}]
```

Comment: this is my ischange file: 2017-05-05 08:24:46,397 WARN  [pool-80-thread.PhaseInterceptorChain... 2017-05-05 08:24:49,444 ERROR [pool-80-thread-1] icationExceptionOutInterceptor...  2017-05-05 08:24:49,408 WARN  [pool-78-thread-1.. 2017-05-05 08:24:52,408 ERROR [pool-78-thread-1...  2017-05-05 08:24:52,408 ERROR [pool-78-thread-1... {... = contents inside}.   In this i need  to read the contents between the dates  not only the matched keyword.

Comment: Do you have a file with a carriage return and line feed at each line or just continuous chunk of characters in one file?

Comment: Not actually..just a chunk of data as I provided a sample above

Comment: If so, I have my own idea to code of your log file. see my edited solution.